# Formula to compare 2 data sets against a value 6 times within 1 cell

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, compare

**Summary:**

I am looking to improve the efficiency of / totally rewrite the formula I have written to compare two different data sets, the output of which will change based on a third data set. This is done 6 times within one statement. My current method works, but I have no doubt there are better ways of doing it, but I'm not sure where to start.

**Use Example:**

If `A1="NO"`, I want to search my 6 datasets and find the first `FALSE` result in `C1`, `F1`, `I1`, `L1`, `O1` or `R1` **regardless of the content in cells** `D1`,`F1`,`J1`,`M1`,`P1` or `S1`, then find out which dataset that `FALSE` is in.

If `A1="YES"`, I want to search my 6 datasets and find the first `FALSE` result in `C1`, `F1`, `I1`, `L1`, `O1` or `R1` **as long as the right adjacent cell has a date before 2012**.

**Example table with above criteria, with the correct output in `FORMULAHERE`:**

| PRE2012 | Data1 | Data1Invalid? | Data1 Date | Data2 | Data2Invalid? | Data2 Date | Data3 | Data3Invalid? | Data3 Date | Data4 | Data4Invalid? | Data4 Date | Data5 | Data5Invalid? | Data5 Date | Data6 | Data6Invalid? | Data6 Date | FORMULAHERE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NO | AAA | TRUE | 01/01/2020 | BBB | FALSE | 01/01/2018 | CCC | TRUE | 01/01/2015 | DDD | TRUE | 01/01/2013 | EEE | TRUE | 01/01/2010 | FFF | FALSE | 01/01/2009 | "USE DATA 2" |
| NO | 111 | FALSE | 01/01/2020 | 222 | FALSE | 01/01/2018 | 333 | TRUE | 01/01/2015 | 444 | TRUE | 01/01/2013 | 555 | TRUE | 01/01/2010 | 666 | FALSE | 01/01/2009 | "USE DATA 1" |
| YES | ABC | TRUE | 01/01/2020 | DEF | FALSE | 01/01/2018 | GHI | TRUE | 01/01/2015 | JKL | TRUE | 01/01/2013 | MNO | TRUE | 01/01/2010 | PQR | FALSE | 01/01/2009 | "USE DATA 6" |
| YES | 123 | TRUE | 01/01/2020 | 456 | FALSE | 01/01/2018 | 789 | TRUE | 01/01/2015 | 012 | TRUE | 01/01/2013 | 345 | FALSE | 01/01/2010 | 678 | FALSE | 01/01/2009 | "USE DATA 5" |

**Current solution:**

Currently, I have the functionality working as I need by using the following *excruciatingly painful* `=IF` statement:

`=IF(A1="Yes",(IF(AND(D1<DATE(2012,1,1),C1=FALSE),"Address 1",IF(A1="Yes",IF(AND(G1<DATE(2012,1,1),F1=FALSE),"Use Data 2",IF(A1="Yes",IF(AND(J1<DATE(2012,1,1),I1=FALSE),"Use Data 3",IF(A1="Yes",IF(AND(M1<DATE(2012,1,1),L1=FALSE),"Use Data 4",IF(A1="Yes",IF(AND(P1<DATE(2012,1,1),O1=FALSE),"Use Data 5",IF(A1="Yes",IF(AND(S1<DATE(2012,1,1),R1=FALSE),"Use Data 6",IF(A1="Yes",IF(R1=TRUE,"All Invalid",IF(A1="Yes",IF(AND(D1>DATE(2012,1,1),G1>DATE(2012,1,1),J1>DATE(2012,1,1),M1>DATE(2012,1,1),P1>DATE(2012,1,1),S1>DATE(2012,1,1)),"No Pre-2012 data on file","Review Manually")))))))))))))))),IF(A1="No",IF(C1=FALSE,"Address 1",IF(F1=FALSE,"Use Data 2",IF(I1=FALSE,"Use Data 3",IF(L1=FALSE,"Use Data 4",IF(O1=FALSE,"Use Data 5",IF(R1=FALSE,"Use Data 6",IF(R1=TRUE,"All Invalid","Review Manually.")))))))))`

What would be the best way to achieve what I am trying to? I am hoping to learn, so any further reading to help me understand an answer would be much appreciated, if possible. Thanks!

Using MSO365. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about including `IFS()` with relative ranges in `XLOOKUP()`:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(C2:R2=FALSE)*(IFS(A2="NO",1,A2="YES",D2:S2<DATE(2012,1,1))),"Use "&B$1:Q$1,"",0)
```

Note that you could replace `""` with any value you'd like to show if no value is found.

---

The logic here:

- `XLOOKUP()` can be used to find a certain value (1st parameter) in a range/array of values (2nd parameter) and would return the relative value on that exact same index/position (3rd parameter). The 4th parameter will return the value if not found, where the 5th parameter is to assert the found value is an exact match rather than approximate;
- 1st Parameter - We are looking for the value '1'. And it will become clear right below;
- 2nd Parameter - We have used nothing but a boolean structure of `TRUE` or `FALSE` values (or numbers). In Excel '(A=X)*(B=Y)' structures would evaluate to something like 'TRUE*TRUE' and thus evaluate further to '1'. In this case we evaluate both `(C2:R2=FALSE)` against `(IFS(A2="NO",1,A2="YES",D2:S2<DATE(2012,1,1)))`. In other words, we will try to find the first position where the above would evaluate to '1';
- 3rd Parameter - A concatenation between "Use" and the range to be returned, relative to the other ranges we used;
- 4th Paremter - Whatever you would like to return if no value is found, set to `""` at the moment;
- 5th Paremter - As mentioned before, this is to assert that we are looking for an exact match rather than an approximate one.

The `IFS()` seems rather self-explainatory but in short: if 'NO' then simply use a '1', otherwise check the range against a date prior to 1-1-2012.

Comment: Once again, you save the day! Thank you so much - this solution works perfectly. I'm interested in learning more to further my understanding, so is there any chance you have any resources the nuances of logic behind this solution, general excel formula tips, or anything else you'd be willing to share about this solution / excel in general? Thanks!

Comment: @Wisp, I tried to put something down. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: This description really helps visualise the process going on here. Thank you so much!